# Create MediatorLiveData with initial value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

Is there a way to initialise `MediatorLiveData` with an initial value?
I want to achieve something like the following:

```kotlin
val myLiveData = MediatorLiveData<String>("initial value")
```

There is a constructor for `MutableLiveData` that takes an initial value as per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#MutableLiveData(T)) but is there a way to do the same thing for `MediatorLiveData`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no constructor for this, but the `apply` scope function is used for setting up objects at their declaration site:

```
val myLiveData = MediatorLiveData<String>().apply {
    value = "initial value"
}
```